# Angular 2: Pass value from attribute directive as a component variable

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

So I have a attribute directive `appGetCurrency` in here:

```
<md-select appGetCurrency [(ngModel)]="value" placeholder="Currency" name="currency">
  <md-option *ngFor="let c of currencyList" [value]="c.code">{{c.dsc}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

I would like that the `appGetCurrency` directive to pass some values to the `currencyList` in order to build the list of options.

**EDIT**

The `appGetCurrency` directive just get a list of currencies from a service, then I would like to pass that list to the `currencyList` variable in the host template:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appGetCurrency]' })

export class CurrencyDirective {
  currencies;

  constructor() {
    // build the <md-options> based on 'currencies' 
    this.currencies = this.service.getCurrencies('asia'); 
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the directive? What does it do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe done. nothing much to it tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an `EventEmitter` just like in a component

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appGetCurrency]' })

export class CurrencyDirective {
  @Output() onCurrencyEvent = new EventEmitter();
  currencies;

  constructor() {
    // build the <md-options> based on 'currencies' 
    this.currencies = this.service.getCurrencies('asia').subscribe((res)=>{
        this.onCurrencyEvent.emit(res);
    }); 
  }

}
```

html:

```
<md-select appGetCurrency [(ngModel)]="value" placeholder="Currency" name="currency" (onCurrencyEvent)="currencyEventOnParent($event)">
```

Parent component:

```
currencyEventOnParent(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass value to directive then you should try like this:

This is my custom directive, and I am going to share two value from componen or HTML.

**test.directive.ts:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[input-box]'
})

export class TestDirectives implements OnInit {
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() value: string;
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("input-box keys  : ", this.name, this.value);
    }
}
```

and now your directive has been created and you will have add this directive into your `app.module.ts` like below:

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestDirectives } from '../directives/test.directive';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestDirectives
  ],
  imports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**You will have to use your directive in your html and send data to the directive like in below code.**

I am sending `name` and `value` to the `test.directive.ts` .

```
<div input-box [name]="'lightcyan'" [value]="'CYAN'"></div>
```

or

```
<div input-box [name]="componentObject.name" [value]="componentObject.value'"></div>
```

Now see the console or use data in the directive accordingly.